# What does "umgekehrt" at the beginning of a sentence mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This fragment comes from the text about the [KaDeWe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaufhaus_des_Westens):

> Umgekehrt prägen Berliner Luft, Pariser Duft und das besondere Flair der Metropole das Image unseres Hauses.

Source: "Direkt", LektorKlett

I don’t understand the phrase *umgekehrt prägen*, and I can’t see the connection between the things mentioned.

Comment: Or maybe the previous sentence said something like "Das KaDeWe prägt mit seiner ausgefallenen Architektur das Stadtbild ..."?

Comment: What is the sentence before? It may be relevant. Possible German synonyms include: "hingegen", "andererseits".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Umgekehrt" normally refers to a text previous to your sentence and is simlilar to "Im Gegensatz dazu" (by contrast). So you need the [prior sentence](http://www.shopmusic.de/2011/12/20/das-kadewe-berlin-wird-seit-dezember-2011-%C3%BCber-das-musikstreaming-system-auracle-sound-beschallt/):

> Das KaDeWe gehört zu Berlin wie das Brandenburger Tor, die
>   Gedächtniskirche und der Fernsehturm. Umgekehrt prägen Berliner Luft,
>   Pariser Duft und das besondere Flair der Metropole das Image unseres
>   Hauses.

This means that on the one hand the KaDeWe is a landmark of Berlin and on the other hand Berlins characteristic traits influence the image of the KaDeWe.

In this case "Umgekehrt" is more like "vice versa" or "reversely", because both (Berlin and KaDeWe) influence each other (in both directions).

Comment: In other words, the "umgekehrt" refers to the fact that KaDeWe : Berlin = Berliner Luft etc. : KaDeWe

Comment: But "Pariser Duft" is a trait that belongs just to the KaDeWe and not to Berlin, right?

Comment: No. In the meaning of this sentence it belongs to the metropolis. But it's an advertising text. I don't think that Pariser Duft is a typical trait of Berlin.

Comment: Are you sure it's not referring to the parfumes being sold inside? Additionally I would suggest "on the other hand/side" or "reversely" as a translation.

Comment: @Carlster: ok, Pariser Duft is probably meant solely independent and not necessarily bound to metropolis/Berlin in this enumeration. But then it is still influencing the image, in the meaning of something from outside is affecting the KaDeWe (irrespective of that they allude to the parfumes inside as a "consequence"). I added "reversely" to the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I never contested that :)